# Qt project files and PREFIX variable

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qmake

I included

```cpp
PREFIX = /usr/local
```

inside my project file and then I run

```cpp
qmake myproject.pro
```

The makefile doesn't say anything about PREFIX though so I assume that i'm doing something wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PREFIX doesn't mean anything in qmake files. The target for files is done via the `target` parameter. So if you want to make PREFIX determine the base location, such as `/usr/local`, you can do do something like this:

```
isEmpty(PREFIX) {
 PREFIX = /usr/local
}
TARGET = myapp
TARGET.path = $$PREFIX/
```

The `isEmpty(PREFIX)` will allow it to be changed during the command line call to qmake, e.g.

```
qmake PREFIX=/opt
```

Comment: Why use the manually defined `PREFIX` variable when there is a standard `INSTALL_ROOT` for this? They serve the same purpose, don't they? Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: This allows you to change the *default* INSTALL_ROOT plus cross platform issues. You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360609/how-to-make-use-of-the-install-root-that-resides-in-generated-makefiles/13736063) for example for details. Note that this is almost a decade ago so times might have changed.

Answer (score 2):

That is INSTALL_ROOT variable on install, try
`make install INSTALL_ROOT="your path"`

Answer (score 0):

If you like to pass PREFIX to qmake, so you can do as follow:

- Open Projects from left pan or using `Ctrl+5` key
- Expand Build Steps
- Add `PREFIX=/your/path/` into Additional arguments field