# How to make use of the INSTALL_ROOT that resides in generated Makefiles?

Tags: qt, qmake

`qmake` generates the following (among the others) rule for installing a target:

```
-$(INSTALL_PROGRAM) "$(TARGET)" "$(INSTALL_ROOT)/$(TARGET)"
```

I cannot set `INSTALL_ROOT` with something like this in a `*.pro` file

```
isEmpty(INSTALL_ROOT) {
    INSTALL_ROOT=/usr
}
```

because `INSTALL_ROOT` is somehow local to generated Makefiles. According to what I've found out so far `INSTALL_ROOT` is empty by default. It could be used like

```
INSTALL_ROOT=$HOME make install
```

when invoking make, which is fine. However I want to be able to specify *default* installation root, say `/usr`. I can do it introducing a new variable `PREFIX` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106442/qt-project-files-and-prefix-variable).
Then generated rule will look like (if `PREFIX` was set to `/usr`)

```
-$(INSTALL_PROGRAM) "$(TARGET)" "$(INSTALL_ROOT)/usr/$(TARGET)"
```

however

```
INSTALL_ROOT=$HOME make install
```

installs target to `/home/<user_name>/usr/$(TARGET)` which is not that one would expect.

So setting `INSTALL_ROOT` to some default value will produce consistent behavior, which is superior to adding `PREFIX`, but how to set `INSTALL_ROOT` in a `*.pro` file?

What is the purpose of `INSTALL_ROOT` is it supposed to be used at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering for Windows here.  You appear to be using UNIX, Linux, or Mac OS X so you may have to make a few changes.

INSTALL_ROOT is a poorly documented feature that appears to have been added so that those without root or admin access can install Qt in their local filesystem.  It's actually a bit of a hack since, as you have already seen, it is not possible to specify an arbitrary target, but you can always move the files to the desired location afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

INSTALL_ROOT is for use with package building systems, like NSIS, debian, or any other way for parcelling up built software and delivering it.

For this purpose you want the result of

```
INSTALL_ROOT=$PWD/package_root make install
```

to create a tree under $PWD/package_root that exactly mimics that on your target system you plan to deliver to.  Note that you need INSTALL_ROOT to be a *full path* (hence the $PWD), not a relative path.

When you create your package you can compress that tree into an archive and then your installation process simply uncompresses the same tree on to the target file-system.

```
$PWD/package_root/usr/bin/my_binary
```

would get installed to

```
/usr/bin/my_binary
```

on the target.

So that is the answer to the question what INSTALL_ROOT is for.  To answer how to specify "default installation root" requires more information about what you want to achieve.

Have a look at the output of qmake -query:

```
sez@ubuntu-11.10:~$ qmake -query
QT_INSTALL_PREFIX:/usr
QT_INSTALL_DATA:/usr/share/qt4
QT_INSTALL_DOCS:/usr/share/qt4/doc
QT_INSTALL_HEADERS:/usr/include/qt4
QT_INSTALL_LIBS:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
QT_INSTALL_BINS:/usr/bin
<snipped>
QT_VERSION:4.7.4
```

and the use of the INSTALLS variable in qmake: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs - and [How do I specify input the QMake INSTALLS variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377593/how-do-i-specify-input-the-qmake-installs-variable)

By default if you just do

```
target.path = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]
INSTALLS += target
```

Then your binary will get installed in whatever qt thinks is the right place, QT_INSTALL_BINS.  You can change those defaults of course by setting target.path to something else.  Qt supplies those paths but its up to you to use them or not.

You could do

```
MY_DEFAULT_INSTALL=/opt/myproj

somedocs.files = docs/index.html
somedocs.path = $$MY_DEFAULT_INSTALL/docs

target.path = $$MY_DEFAULT_INSTALL/bin

INSTALLS += somedocs target
```

for example, where MY_DEFAULT_INSTALL is the one place in your .pro file that defines the default for installs.