# How do I specify input the QMake INSTALLS variable?

Tags: qt, qmake

In my Qt project I'm trying to copy libraries as part of the build process. The goal is to have a ready made distribution after the build with all necessary dynamic libraries.

This seems acheivable with the INSTALLS variable, but I find the documentation a bit thin:
[qmake Variable Reference: INSTALLS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#installs)

In the example given:

- Is `target` already defined, or is defined by writing `target.path =`?
- Where is the documentation for possible members? `.path` and ...?

Comment: Looks like `target` is defined in the example. The output in the makefile is a definition of `install_target`. There were some errors related to the referencing variables.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yeah, the docs have much to be desired here.

`target` is already defined, but that is a special case. You can define your own additional deployment sets. Here is how we specify the image format plugins:

```
imageformats.path = /opt/some/path/bin/imageformats
imageformats.files += $$[QT_INSTALL_DATA]/plugins/imageformats/*.so
INSTALLS += imageformats
```

Here is the minimal documentation about the three commands: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs

```
yourset.path = /path/in/which/to/install/files
yourset.files = /files/to/install
yourset.extra = custom commands to run, eg. `touch somefile.txt`
INSTALLS += yourset
```

Answer (score 10):

`target` is whatever string you want to use. It is your own identifier.

`target.files` defines what you want to install.

`target.path` is the location (directory) you want to put the `target.files` in.

For example, let's say I have a file called "config.xml" that I want to copy to the directory "xyzzy".  I would use the following in my qmake .pro file to specify that.

```
my_file.files = config.xml
my_file.path = xyzzy

INSTALLS += my_file
```

BTW, to actually make the file copy, you will have to execute `make install`.

You may also find the answer helpful in understanding: [Copy a file to build directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7795397/copy-a-file-to-the-build-directory-after-compiling-project-with-qt).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Is `%{buildDir}` valid syntax or just to illustrate. I tried it, but in Qt Creator the expression is never evaluated :(

Comment: @eriktheblond The example in the link assumes `buildDir` has already been defined somewhere in the qmake .pro file  (i.e. `buildDir = a/b/c`).

Comment: @jwernerny Good answer except target is actually a "built-in" and a bit special, not whatever you want to use. It correlates to the TARGET. See - https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html#installs.

Comment: @EirikM *Maybe* in an older version, in Qt 5.5 onwards, you may do the following (an example). Somewhere in your `Project.pro` file `LIB_DIR = ../libs` and later, `MY_LIB = $$LIB_DIR/my_lib/`