# Qmake Qt: Move Header file to build folder

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I'm new to Qt, with a C# background.

I am creating Dym Libs for a few projects. I want to have the Header files moved to the build folder during compile **OR** know how to include the Header file in the lib.

Any suggestions on how to make my lib a full package without having to copy/paste the header files, or the best approach for distribution would be great.

Cheers

Comment: More precisely: what do you mean "include the Header file in the lib"?

Comment: @Ethouris In order to access the classes of the lib, you have to had the header file. If i don't have the .h file with the lib, the importing project cannot find the classes.

Comment: Creating packages is a strongly system-dependent thing. The best you can think of is to have them installable in the selected PREFIX directory (the answer you've got), however it still doesn't provide you with a single file of the library. This must be done with the system's packaging facility, of course, with the use of "installed" files.

A good practice, if you create a library, is also to provide the pkg-config file (*.pc), which specifies whatever specific "cflags" and "ldflags" must be passed to compile and link commands.

Comment: Thank you @Ethouris, for the details. C# makes people un aware and lazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`INSTALLS` qmake variable](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#installing-files)

```
public_headers.path = include
public_headers.files = include/*.h

INSTALLS += public_headers
```

Then you can call `make install` (with a proper prefix, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7106823/256138)), which should result in the headers being installed alongside the binaries.